# PackageReference or ProjectReference causes TypeLoadException error in Analyzer

Tags: roslyn, vsix

I have an analyzer which has a PackageReference called `ClassMarker`.

This reference contains a type `Marker1`.

Debugging the analyzer with the VSIX project, everything works fine.

Then, when I add a reference to the `Marker1` type, I start getting runtime errors in the output window.

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll Exception thrown:'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' in mscorlib.dll

The particular line which causes the error is:

```
var MarkerTypeName = typeof(Marker1).FullName;
```

I've used the same approach with a ProjectReference as well.

I take this to mean that `Marker1` isn't being loaded properly by the VSIX extension.

I've tried a few different approaches to make sure it's included when the vsix project runs (added PackageReference to VSIX project, [Added a VSIXSourceItem using workaround](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5899)).

How do you make a PackageReference or ProjectReference (and any of its dependencies) accessible in the VSIX instance at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was an issue of the visual studio cache not being cleared out.  After going into the solution and deleting the .vs folder, clearing the symbol cache and uninstalling all the extensions from the debugging instance of visual studio the analyzer started to work.

Comment: Another bug that seems to persist until nowadays with VS 2022 is that sometimes Visual Studio will close but leave a VBCScompiler process running in the background and it causes all kinds of havoc and thrown Exceptions, this one included